# Ensure a task takes at least a certain amount of time using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I am developing a splash screen for an Android app which has a few requirements:

1. While the splash screen is showing I need to fetch a value from a
   repository. Once that value is fetched it will be used to kick off 3
   different calls to the repository in parallel.
2. The splash screen
   must show for at least 3 seconds or as long as it takes to fetch all
   values from the repository (if the fetches take longer than 3
   seconds).
3. If an error occurs when fetching the first value from
   the repository then the observable chain can terminate (once 3
   seconds have elapsed)
4. If any errors occur when fetching the next
   three values the observable chain should not terminate, that is, all
   three should run even if one or more fail.

Here's what I have currently:

```
    Observable<Long> timerObservable = Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    cachedObservable = mLoginRepository
            .fetchLoginPreference()
            .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, LoginPreference>() {
                @Override
                public LoginPreference call(Throwable throwable) {
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<LoginPreference, Observable<CompositeLPLCPalette>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<CompositeLPLCPalette> call(final LoginPreference loginPreference) {
                    if (loginPreference == null
                            || loginPreference.getActivationCode() == null
                            || loginPreference.getActivationCode().isEmpty()) {
                        Timber.d("login preference was null");
                        return Observable.just(null);
                    }

                    final String activationCode = loginPreference.getActivationCode();

                    Observable<LoginCapability> loginCapabilityObservable = mLoginRepository
                            .fetchLoginCapability(activationCode, true)
                            .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, LoginCapability>() {
                                @Override
                                public LoginCapability call(Throwable throwable) {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            });

                    Observable<OrgContactInfo> orgContactInfoObservable = mLoginRepository
                            .fetchOrgContactInfo(activationCode, true)
                            .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, OrgContactInfo>() {
                                @Override
                                public OrgContactInfo call(Throwable throwable) {
                                    Timber.d("Error fetching org contact info");
                                    return null;
                                }
                            });

                    Observable<Palette> paletteObservable = mLoginRepository
                            .fetchThemeInformation(activationCode, true)
                            .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, Palette>() {
                                @Override
                                public Palette call(Throwable throwable) {
                                    Timber.d("Error fetching Palette");
                                    return null;
                                }
                            });

                    return Observable.zip(loginCapabilityObservable,
                            paletteObservable,
                            orgContactInfoObservable,
                            new Func3<LoginCapability, Palette, OrgContactInfo, CompositeLPLCPalette>() {
                                @Override
                                public CompositeLPLCPalette call(LoginCapability loginCapability, Palette palette, OrgContactInfo orgContactInfo) {
                                    return new CompositeLPLCPalette(loginCapability, loginPreference, palette);
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .zipWith(timerObservable, new Func2<CompositeLPLCPalette, Long, CompositeLPLCPalette>() {
                @Override
                public CompositeLPLCPalette call(CompositeLPLCPalette compositeLPLCPalette, Long aLong) {
                    return compositeLPLCPalette;
                }
            });
```

The code above works but I have a few questions:

1) Is the way I'm enforcing the 3 second minimum the correct way to do it? It looked like there was a delay operator as well as the timer operator and it wasn't clear which I should use. Also, should I be zipping the timer operator with the rest of the chain?

2) Am I using onErrorReturn() correctly if my intention is that if the observable fails it should just return null instead of having the subscriber's onError() method?

3) In the flatMap() operator I'm checking to see if loginPreference is null, has a null activation code or empty activation code and if any of those things are true I don't want to run the other 3 observables. Is there a different operator I should be using before the flatMap() operator instead of adding this logic to flatMap()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yep, that's the correct way to do it. I would suggest extracting the contents of the `flatMap` as a separate method, and keep the 2 zip operators separate for logic and maintenance reasons.
2. I really don't like having nulls in observables, at a minimum it's incompatible with RxJava 2. However given the requirements the logic feels sound.
3. Nah, you're good.

Comment: Regarding your answer to #2, why do you not like having nulls in observables?

Comment: `at a minimum it's incompatible with RxJava 2` - and it's really hard to switch existing code to non-nulls (have tried it...)